# jagged bidimensional arrays and contiguous memory in c#

Tags: c#, memory, block, jagged-arrays

I have seen that declaring a bidimensional array as a jagged array is fine

```
int[][] jagged = new int[3][];
```

but when doing some optimization at memory level in code, it is more convenient to use `[,]` as a definition of a matrix and use blocks of memory...

so can you explain if this is true?
I guess the `[,]` takes a block of memory and the access of elements is faster rather than lookimg in several parts of memory in a jagged bidimensional array....

Comment: I think you really want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when an array is allocated as `[,]` , it is always given contiguous memory, so depending on what you want to do, it may be faster, convenient, etc